# Querying ElasticSearch SQL filtering by @timestamp

Tags: sql, datetime, elasticsearch

I want to perform a query using SQL syntax in elastic search using URL /_sql and use in the where clause a filter for dates. So far if in the body I use this query

```
{
    "query": "SELECT count(*) from logstash where Severity='ERROR'"
}
```

I get some results, then if I try to filter by @timestamp

```
{
    "query": "SELECT Time from logstash where Severity='ERROR'  and '@timestamp' > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTES"
}
```

And instead of getting 0 in the count or a shorter number than before I simply get nothing if I remove the quotes around @timestamp there it raises an error (not expecting the @ symbol), and if I use timestamp then suggest me to use @timestamp as timestamp is not a valid field.

How can I filter by @timestamp? Or how should I escape the @ symbol for the field?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of surrounding with simple quotes I needed to surround with double quotes, so:

```
{
    "query": "SELECT count(*) from logstash where Severity='ERROR' and \"@timestamp\" > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTES"
}
```

worked.